# Rounded Rectangle In Delphi

Tags: delphi

i have been trying to draw a rounded rectangle with spacing in the border, but i cant seem to find a way to do this using the Canvas.RoundRect function, and i am not that good in maths to draw the edges myself, i can draw a rectangle with spacing using the Canvas.MoveTo and Canvas.LineTo functions, but i dont know how to make the edges rounded. Currently what i am doing is i make yellow rectangle at the place where i want to make the spacing in the border but the problem is when i am printing i have to directly draw on printer canvas and i have to draw on a transparent sheet, so a background color will cause problems. Anyone who can help me build a custom drawing routine or tell me how can i erase that area and still print on a transparent paper without any background color. The yellow background color is just for a preview, when i am drawing to a printer canvas the background is transparent.

See the image to know what i mean by spacing in the border line.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `Canvas.Brush := bsClear`?

Comment: I don't understand your initial problem. Canvas.RoundRect doesn't draw? It doesn't draw where you want it? Or something else?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz problem is to draw "space" at the bottom line of the rect with transparent background

Comment: @teran - Thanks! I thought the spacing was about some outer margin. I should notice the space in the picture.

Comment: The problem is i cant draw the spacing in the border with roundrect, i have been trying to make my own function for round rectangle but i cant make the edges round.

Comment: why not to make solid roundrect and later paint the gap with background color with fillrect?

Comment: see drawing code here: http://pastebin.com/g83kvp3B

Comment: Who says there's a background color that's appropriate to paint as a solid rectangle, @Arioch? As the question said, the solid yellow background in the given picture is just an example. We might be painting over something that already has stuff painted in the background. We might be printing to transparent media.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can exclude the gap by manipulating the clipping region of the current device context. Assuming that L, R, T and B are the coordinates of your yellow rectangle to make the gap, use the following code:

```
ExcludeClipRect(Canvas.Handle, L, T, R, B); // exclude the gap
Canvas.RoundRect(<whatever you already do here>);
SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, 0); // reset the clipping region
```

Answer (score 4):

You can draw your partial rounded rectangle yourself. Use `MoveTo` and `LineTo` for the straight portions, and use [`Arc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Arc) for the corners.

The `Arc` function draws a portion of an ellipse. The first two pairs of coordinates to the function indicate the bounds of the ellipse. If you want the corners of your rectangle to be circular, then the ellipse is a circle, and `X2 - X1` will equal `Y2 - Y1`. The second two pairs of coordinates indicate the starting and ending points on the circle; they'll be the same points you pass to `MoveTo` and `LineTo` for the straight portions. The arc is drawn counter-clockwise.

Comment: It is important to know whether the arc is drawn counter-clockwise or clockwise. That's because the GDI convention is to draw a the first point of a line, but not draw the last point of a line. The documentation mentions this for LineTo but not for Arc. For LineTo it says "The LineTo function draws a line from the current position up to, but not including, the specified point." Presumably the same convention holds for Arc. All this means that you should draw your straight line sections in the same counter-clockwise sense.

Comment: At the API level, you can control which direction arcs are drawn with [`SetArcDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162961.aspx). I don't think `TCanvas` exposes that setting, but I suspect you could use the API, and `TCanvas` would honor it.

Comment: In fact the Emba documentation you link to suggests that you do exactly that if you want to reverse the sense. Personally I'd just leave the sense at its default setting and follow the counter-clockwise convention.

Comment: Yep thanks for the help but when i tried to draw a rectangle myself with moveto and lineto but the arc api was so hard to use that i dont know how i can make a perfect edge for the rectangle, hopefull the solution UWE Raabe told solved the problem.

Comment: Teran provided [example code](http://pastebin.com/g83kvp3B) for calling `Arc`. Have you tried drawing anything yourself? Get a pencil and some paper, and draw the pieces you need. Mark the coordinates. Then implement it in code.